# Android: Custom AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created a custom alertdialog by the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ActivityName.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
                builder.setView(layout);
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
```

Problem is the pop up is surrounded with the default Dialog background having a own void space of a title(as the title is not set). How do i remove this. I have tried putting custom style through `ContextThemeWrapper` like 
`builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getParent(), R.style.CustomDialogTheme));`

But its not working. How do i do that?!!! Thanks in Advance.
Custom style xml is given below:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert">
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
```

[image: This is the output on the emulator]

Comment: Not showing a title is going to confuse the user, you should show a title on the Dialog, because its the expected standard.

Comment: i attached the title within the layout(i.e. "Set As..." as you can see)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use following

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Inflate your layout and set the view to content of dialog and

```
dialog.setContentView(view);
```

Comment: thanks jitendra !! it removes the default background but i have another issue now. That, the application im working is set to Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen but when the dialog pop's up the top title bar slides down again and the dialog is not in the center position rather on the top-left(default) position of the window. Can you help me about this???

Comment: use Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar.Fullscreen);

Comment: As an update - I used this method and fixed the center issue using XML by laying the custom dialog in a relative layout and setting gravity to center. Using Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen did not fix the centering issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
.create();
```

In order to listen for UI events:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_button);
btn.setOnClickListener(blah blah);
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setView(view)
  .create();
```